# Substitution of propagator to a product in Zinn-Justin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

I'm reading Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena, 4th ed., by Zinn-Justin and on page 127 he defines an action $$S_{\epsilon}[\phi]=\int{dxdy} \phi(x)\phi(y)[K(x,y) + \epsilon ] + V(\phi).$$
From this action he arrives to a propagator defined  by
$$\Delta_\epsilon (x,y).=\Delta(x,y)-\epsilon\eta(x)\eta(y)+O(\epsilon^2)$$
where $$\eta(x)=\int{\Delta(x,z)dz}$$
Then he says If we now expand a Feynman diagram with the new propagator $\Delta_\epsilon (x,y)$  at
first order in $\epsilon$, we obtain a sum of terms in which in all possible ways a propagator $\Delta$ has been replaced by the product  $-\eta(x)\eta(y)$.

Can anyone proof me why this is true?